# How to compare two arrays and add keys from one array to another

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays

> 1st array

first array containts 60 strings like this:

`['string1','string2', ... , string60];`

> 2nd array

And I have an associative array like this:

`['Key' => value, ..., 'Key' => value]`

What I need to do is compare each value from first array(that contains 60 ellements), with each ***key*** from the second array, and if second(associative) array doesn't contain key that matches any value from first array - I should add such ellement to the associative array.

For example second array doesn't have key that matches `string5` for example, and I'm not talking about value of the key, I'm literally talking about `Key` itself. So now I need to add `string5` as a new key => value ellement to the array, the `Key` must be the word `string5`, and the `value` must be empty.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: `Foreach ($array1 as $key) {if isset ($array2 [$key]) {...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not more complicated than:

```
$combined = $array2 + array_fill_keys($array1, null);
```

`array_fill_keys` creates an array like `['string1' => null, ..]`, `+` adds all of these keys *which don't already exists in `$array2`*.

Comment: Interested to know why this was downvoted. Tested it myself and works as one would expect.

Comment: Knee-jerk reactions of *"this can't possibly work"*... :o)

Comment: Tested it with two arrays of 500.000 records each (random keys/values as a string). This way is slower compared to my solution (kinda suprised me). This solution took around 0.53 to 0.61 seconds. Mine solution take around the 0.40 seconds. So if you have big or complicated arrays to loop though my solution might be more suitable, but I would prefer the cleanness of this solution thouh. EDIT: Also tested with an array_flip instead of array_fill_keys. That one is even slower.

Comment: You're just looping once, while this here loops at least twice. However, loops here are native C loops, while yours are PHP loops. You gain a little, you lose more. However, ~.55 vs .4 for such a *massive* array is still plenty fast enough IMO, and I prefer the conciseness of this statement as well.

Answer (score 1):

$combined = $array2 + array_fill_keys($array1, null);// key value will be maintained

array_values($array2); //index starts from 0

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
foreach($array_1 as $val) {
   if(!isset($array_2[$val])) {
       $array_2[$val] = null;
   }
}
```

pretty sure there are people who know more efficient ways (resource wise) as this might take long when you have huge arrays.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the logical way to do this.
>   First divide the second array in key and values array. I mean two different array.

So

```
$keys = array_keys($array2);
$values = array_values($array2);
```

now you have to take the different from $array1 to $array2 sigular or vice-versa ( Depends on your requirement ) and it will give you the difference of missing keys.

```
$diff = array_diff($array1,$keys);
```

Now you will be able to find it easily.

[Please refer to array_diff Source: php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $required = array('key1', 'key2', 'key3','key4');

  $data = array(
      'key1' => 10,
      'key2' => 20
  );

  $arrayDiff = array_diff_key(array_flip($required),$data);
  $final = array_merge($data,$arrayDiff);
  // Result
  // Array
  //(
  //    [key1] => 10
  //    [key2] => 20
  //    [key3] => 2
  //    [key4] => 3
  //)
?>
```

If you want default value to be populated to the new keys added to the array, add below line before merge and use the variable $arrayFill instead of $arrayDiff in the merge statement

```
$arrayFill = array_fill_keys(array_flip($arrayDiff),0);
```